# Adding subview to main view in tableViewController adds subview to table view instead of view in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a UITableViewController in which I have some content, I am then trying to add a UIView to the `view` such that it is positioned absolutely over the tableView and does not scroll with it. However, when I try to add the view to the screen with

`view.addSubview(fixPositionedView)`

It is placed into the tableView and scrolls with it. Does anybody know how I can give my `fixPositionedView` fixed positioning so that it doesn't move with the rest of the scroll view?

Comment: add it to the parentView of the view? Screenshots and more details about your current setup would be quite helpful to understand the problem and come up with solutions.

Answer (score 3):

All good, I figured it out. I have to change `view.addSubview(fixPositionedView)` to `view.superview?.addSubview(fixPositionedView)`